# Pintar string en html con Jinja2

Tags: html, python, string, template

Quiero pintar un sucesión de *strings* que he ido acumulando en un diccionario en un archivo de *python*.

El código que comento en el **main** es el siguiente:

```
                    for variable in config[id].values():
                    variable.setValores(d)
                    fila += "," + str(variable.getValue())
                arrayData += fila + ","
                return (arrayData)
```

El trozo de código que he elaborado en el **template** es:

```
        {% for element in arrayDatos %}
        <ul>
            {{element|join(", ")}}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
```

La cosa es que cuando imprime en el *template* las palabras lo hace, pero en lugar de agrupadas en una línea lo hace tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Habría manera de gestionar eso directamente con Jinja2 para que en lugar de letra por letra me lo mostrase palabra por palabra?.

```
variable1
variable2
variable3
```

He andado buscando información pero no he dado con la tecla. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

En la variable arrayDatos del contexto tienes un string, no una lista, por lo que estás iterando por cada carácter del string (aparte, luego estás intentando hacer un join no sé muy bien para qué :/). Es bastante probable que la tengas inicializada como string en lugar de como lista:

```py
# arrayData = ""
arrayData = []
```

Otra opción (si por lo que sea es necesario que trabajes con un string), es pasarlo al contexto como una lista simplemente haciendo un split:

```py
return (arrayData.split(','))
```

Y si por cualquier razón lo quieres hacer directamente en el template puedes hacer el split ahí:

```
{% set elements = arrayDatos.split(',') %}
{% for element in elements %}
    <ul>
        {{element}}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```